# Snaptcha failing if multiple User registration forms on same page

Tags: captcha, snaptcha

I'm using snaptcha for Solspace User registration forms. Background info here: [User registration failing Snaptcha security test every time](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18442/user-registration-failing-snaptcha-security-test-every-time)

There are two registration forms on the page - one for each of two possible member groups you can sign up for. The form you choose will be displayed inside a modal box.

If there's only one form, it works just fine. User who should pass the security test do. But when I add a second user registration form for the second member group, neither form will submit. They always fail the security test.

When inspecting the code, I see that both User registration forms have the same snaptcha field (same ID and value), and I imagine it's the lack of a unique code for each form that is causing the problem.

How can I use Snaptcha successfully when I have multiple User registration forms on the same page?

Comment: Can I manually insert the snaptcha code into the form rather than using the {exp:snaptcha:field} tag and then change all the IDs and value to something unique?

Comment: Why wouldn't you add the member group as a select list negating the need for 2 forms ?

Comment: The process of group selection requires a bit of explanation and it's not very well suited to a simple select box. So I've chosen to have group selection as a separate first step, and then once you choose the right group you proceed to the correct registration form based on the group you chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, as posted by Ben in the devot-ee support forums, is to try making each tag unique as follows:

```
{exp:snaptcha:field id="1"}

{exp:snaptcha:field id="2"}
```

That fixed it  for me. I now have two user registration forms on the same page and both submit as they should.